# RESTful Web Services for Geometry Operations

Tags: web-service, rest

I'm trying to get an idea of what web services exist for doing geometry operations. I know that Esri's [GeometryService](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/geometryserver.html) supports several operations, but does anything else exist? I've started a very simple [project](https://github.com/atogle/jts-geometry-service) built on JTS and Google App Engine to support a Code for America project and am trying to decide if I should build it out or not. Any thoughts?

Comment: looks great, I say build it out! you might want to support GeoJson in addition to WKT, might be easier for clients to call

Comment: Thanks Brian, I think I will. GeoJSON support will be near the top of this list.

Answer (score 3):

The best RESTful GIS implementation I have seen so far is Open Source: [FeatureServer](http://featureserver.org/)
It is a true RESTful implementation, meaning that it really uses HTTP methods to offer [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) methods for geographic objects.

It offers many kind of storage, including PostGis, and it is very easy to use it from within OpenLayers.

Keep in mind that if you are going to choose for a RESTful implementation, you are not going to use the OGC standards (WFS and REST are not friends): this can not be an option in many cases.

Comment: sorry, I read again your question and I am afraid I misunderstood you. It seems that you need a RESTfull implementation of a WPS, and I do not know any of them (I use pyWPS but it is not RESTful).

Comment: Cleaned up your links, hope you don't mind.

Comment: just found this project: http://code.google.com/p/postgis-restful-web-service-framework/ looks like something could be used in this context