# Show whole track in QGIS animation

Tags: qgis, animation

I mostly followed [Creating animated route map in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191955) for animating a route on QGIS. The main thing I did differently is that I started with a csv with timestamped lat/lon data, converted it to a GPX file using GPS Visualizer and skipped the step for adding timestamps but my animation only shows the current position, not the track.

How do I show the track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps 1 through 5 of that guide are about creating a time-stamped route. You already have time-stamped data, so those steps are not appropriate for your situation.

Add your CSV into QGIS as a delimited text layer. Proceed from Step 6: Fix Symbology.

Comment: Thanks for the response, being able to use the csv directly in QGIS saves me a step but doesn't solve my problem.  My animation still only shows the location at that instant, not the entire trace.

Comment: check the box for "accumulate features"

Comment: Thanks csk - I just saw that even though I had selected 'no end time - accumulate features' it wasn't checked when I looked through the layer details.  I came back to update my comments and see that you had answered it before I got back here.